# Programatically detecting events from UI elements

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've looking at some arcane construct namely this:

```
cell.phoneNumberField.removeEventHandlers(forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
cell.phoneNumberField.addEventHandler(forControlEvents: .EditingChanged) { field in
    self.formValues[formField.id] = (field as! //...)
}
```

In Swift 2, those 2 method calls have either vanished into existence. I'm having trouble finding suitable replacements for the calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

```
textField.addTarget(nil, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

and then handle the event with `textChanged` function

```
func textChanged(sender: UITextField){
    print(sender.text)
}
```